# Referencing a Many2many field in a format string in a Kanban view

Tags: python, view, odoo, kanban

In my Kaban views, I have a Many2many field named `pages`. If i use `<field name="pages" />` in the Kanban view template, it works fine and show the Many2many tags. However, if I use: `<img t-attf-src="/rescrap/static/OUTPUT/{{ record.pages.raw_value[0].site }}.jpg" />`.

The part `{{ record.pages.raw_value[0].site }}` return undefined when I check with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this.

```
<img t-att-src="kanban_image('res.users', 'image_small', member)"/>
```

It might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I'm aware of `kanban_image` function. However, my images aren't store in the database, but they are static images which are stored in under the `static` folder in my module.